# How to add second scrollbar on top in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular

I was trying to add another scrollbar on top of a div containing a large table.
I had to solve it by pieces from here and there.
This is my solution in vanillaJS/Angular which actually works:

```
scroll() {
    let scroller = document.querySelector('.above-scroller');
    let table = document.querySelector('.table');
    table.scrollTo(scroller.scrollLeft,0);
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="above-scroller" (scroll)="scroll()">
  <div class="scroller"></div>
</div>
<div class="table" >
  <table></table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.above-scroller  {
   overflow-x: scroll;
   overflow-y:hidden;
   height: 20px;
   width: 1200px
 }

.scroller {
  width:4500px;
  height: 20px;
}

.table {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A proper Angular 2+ solution would be to mark the divs with # sign and use ViewChild to reference them:

HTML

```
<div class="above-scroller" #scroller (scroll)="scroll()">
  <div class="scroller"></div>
</div>
<div class="table" #table >
  <table></table>
</div>
```

Angular Component:

```
@ViewChild('scroller') scroller: ElementRef; 
@ViewChild('table') table: ElementRef;

this.table.nativeElement.scrollTo(this.scroller.nativeElement.scrollLeft,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I kind of get inspired by @JakubBares idea and my solution looks like this:

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="topScrollbar" #topScrollBar><div [style.width]="topScrollbarWidth"></div></div>
    <div #regularScrollBar>
     //   My original content which with scrollbar
    </div
```

**Typescript:**
    
Use @ViewChild to have easy access to elements

```
@ViewChild('topScrollBar') topScrollBar: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('regularScrollBar') regularScrollBar: ElementRef;
```

Once the page is loaded you can call method to calculateTopScrollBar. Method will calculate initial scroll bar with and add listener to do the same every time we scroll with top or bottom scroll bar

```
private calculate(): void {
    setTimeout(() => this.topScrollbarWidth = this.regularScrollBar.nativeElement.scrollWidth + 'px', 0);

    this.regularScrollBar.nativeElement.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        if (this.showScrollBar()) {
            this.topScrollbarWidth = this.regularScrollBar.nativeElement.scrollWidth + 'px';
            this.topScrollBar.nativeElement.scrollLeft = this.regularScrollBar.nativeElement.scrollLeft;
        }
    });

    this.topScrollBar.nativeElement.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        if (this.showScrollBar()) {
            this.topScrollbarWidth = this.regularScrollBar.nativeElement.scrollWidth + 'px';
            this.regularScrollBar.nativeElement.scrollLeft = this.topScrollBar.nativeElement.scrollLeft;
        }
    });
}

private showScrollBar(): boolean {
    return this.regularScrollBar.nativeElement.scrollWidth > this.regularScrollBar.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
}
```

Don't forget to clean up:

```
public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.regularScrollBar.nativeElement.removeAllListeners();
    this.topScrollBar.nativeElement.removeAllListeners();
}
```